# Onclick delegate with OR condtion JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a refresh button on which I if I press the button there should be ajax call.

```
if (($('#smart_sheet_area').is(':empty')) || ($(".page-content").delegate(".refresh-smartsheet", "click")){
  //my ajax call
  //function logic that makes refresh-button dynamically.
}
```

Now the above condition checks if the div smart_sheet_area is empty then only ajax call should work, here I added an OR condtion in which the ajax call should also run when the refresh-smartsheet button is pressed.

Here the smart_sheet_area is empty condition is working fine but the when clicking on refresh button nothing is happening.

And no error is been shown in console.

Comment: `delegate()` doesn't return a boolean, why are you using it in `if`? It's also deprecated, you should use `.on()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the AJAX code in a function. Then you can call it when the page loads, and also when the button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function do_ajax() {
        // AJAX code
    }

    if ($('#smart_sheet_area').is(':empty')) {
        do_ajax();
    }
    
    $(".page-content").on("click", ".refresh-smartsheet", do_ajax);
});
```

Comment: no brother, i want both of them in OR condition. Because ajax call are 2 times when the div is empty and second when refresh btn click.

Comment: That makes no sense. An event is not a condition you can "OR".

Comment: An event is something that happens, and when it happens you run a function to process it.

Comment: let me explain when the page loads and smart_sheet_area div is empty than the div will get html using ajax call no need to press the btn. but now i also want to do ajax call on refresh btn. getting sir?

Comment: Now I understand. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I thought of this solution once, but is there any way with OR condition, just asking if its possible ? else this answer is totally perfect and working. Thanks

Comment: No, there's no way with OR. You don't understand how things work if you think you can do that.